# sshpass from iplist and run tcptraceroute

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

Number of servers in a list = 40

I want to run tcptraceroute on each server for all 40 ips in the list. for this i need to loop sshpass and run tcptracetraceroute.

When i run the below code, it just runs for first ip in list and use same ip to run tcptraceroute and exits.

```
IFS=$IFS,
  USER='*********'
  PASSWORD='********'
  PORT='22'
    while read ip; do
        sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -i turbot -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
        $USER@$ip "sudo -s /usr/bin/tcptraceroute "$ip" $PORT" >>Res.txt

    done < .PrivateIP-List.txt
```

I'm trying to output the traceroute results to Res.txt file

Comment: In your approach you need two loops - one connect to the ips (you have it) and second run trace over all ips (missing). You will probably need to save `.PrivateIP-List.txt` file into variable to pass is through ssh. Consider using ssh paswordless - just run `ssh-copy-id user@ip` then you can use e.g. GNU Parallel like: `parallel -j40 --tag --nonall --slf .PrivateIP-List.txt uptime` That's much faster.

Comment: @lojza tcptraceroute runs does sshpass to first ip and runs trace for that ip and then goes to second ip runs trace for second ip. As shown in below output. 
traceroute to 10.233.17.42 (10.233.17.42), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ip-10-233-17-42.ec2.internal (10.233.17.42) <syn,ack>  0.027 ms  0.006 ms  0.006 ms
traceroute to 10.233.25.132 (10.233.25.132), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  aayauva025132 (10.233.25.132) <syn,ack>  0.023 ms  0.008 ms  0.005 ms
traceroute to 10.233.58.167 (10.233.58.167), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

Comment: @lojza My Modified Code: 
while read ip; do
        sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -i turbot -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
        $USER@$ip <<EOT 
for i in $(cat $File);
do
"sudo -s /usr/bin/tcptraceroute "$i" $PORT" >>Res.txt
done
    done < .PrivateIP-List.txt